# Line integral along a sphere

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to take the line integral across an arc in $\mathbb{R}^3$ across a sphere centred at the origin of radius $a$. I want this line integral to simply follow the sphere from $(a,0,0)$ to $(0,a,0)$ to $(0,0,a)$ back to $(a,0,0)$

I have some vector field: $F(x,y,z) = (y+z)I + (x+z)j + (x+z)k$

Comment: How does going through a quarter of a circle of radius $\;a\;$ means "going from $\;x=a\;$ to $\;z=a\;$" ?? What are these things $\;x,z\;$ ? Also, are you in the space $\;\Bbb R^3\;$ ? I ask because of your supposed parametrization, but then **what** quarter of *what* circle do you need?

Comment: @DonAntonio Sorry, yes I am in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and I am imply taking a path along a sphere of radius $a$. This path goes from $(1,0,0)$ to $(0,0,1)$. Sorry that I wasn't as clear previously.

Comment: You know you can edit your own comment within 5 minutes after you posted? You don't need to write a new comment...

Comment: If you're taking $\;0\le t\le 1\;$, then you need each coordinate of your parametrization to be multiplied by $\;a\;$ ...and interchange the sine and the cosine.

Comment: Do you know the spherical coordinates $x = r\cos\theta \sin\phi,\ y = r\sin\theta \sin\phi, z = r\cos \phi$? You can write $r$, $\theta$ and $\phi$ as functions of a parameter $t$ to get different curves on the sphere.

Comment: @M.Vinay wouldn't that yield a surface integral?

Comment: @DisplayName (... well, that's a weird name)

No, if you use a single parameter $t$, you'll get a $x = x(t),\ y = y(t),\ z = z(t)$, which is a curve. If you use two parameters, you'll get a surface.
Here the key is to take $r = a$, so whatever curve you obtain will lie on the sphere.

Comment: @DisplayName What I mean is, when $r=a$ in the spherical coordinates, you basically get a parametrization of the sphere (surface): $x = a\cos\theta \sin\phi,\ y = a\sin\theta \sin\phi,\ z = a\cos\phi$ with parameters $\theta$ and $\phi$. Now if you write both $\theta$ and $\phi$ in terms of a single parameter $t$, you get a curve on the surface of the sphere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substituting $r = a$ in the spherical coordinates yields
$x = a\cos\theta \sin\phi,\ y = a\sin\theta \sin\phi,\ z = a\cos\phi$
which is a parametric representation of the sphere. Any curve lying on the sphere can be obtained as parametric equations of the form $\theta = \theta(t),\ \phi = \phi(t)$.

If you want a curve on the sphere that goes from $(a, 0, 0)$ to $(0, a, 0)$, first observe that $\theta = 0,\ \phi = \pi/2$ at $(a, 0, 0)$, and $\theta = \pi/2,\ \phi = \pi/2$ at $(0, a, 0)$. So *one* possible curve is:
$\theta(t) = t,\ \phi(t) = 0;\ 0 \le t \le \pi/2$.

Similarly, you can find the other curves.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is not hard to do the integration explicitly in spherical coordinates, the easiest way is to take the curl of the vector field, and compute the resulting flux through the part of the surface of the sphere enclosed by your curve. Then by Stokes theorem you get the answer to your question. The simplification in your case comes from the fact that curl is going to be constant, and you will just have to compute the area of some projection of the surface.